# How to improve the fetching of related content?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm working a **Rails 3.2** heavily content oriented website with around 3m~ records on our main MySQL (MariaDB) table.

On a `#show` action we show 5 lists with 20~ related records (of the same model), each listing using a different column to match against (like a `category_id` column).

We are having a **lot** of performance problems on these related content sections and we're looking for a way to improve it.

We have already indexed all columns, optimized queries (no JOINS are being made) and tried fragment caching the loops... And still, most of these queries take between 500ms and 3s each.

From where we are now, I can imagine the following solutions:

1. Add ElasticSearch and use it to find related content
2. Add Varnish and cache the whole page
3. Create a intermediate "related" service class that will fetch each of the related record lists and store a **list of IDs** on Redis with a key like `content/2/most_viewed_by_category`, and later use this list to fetch the records from the database again. This cache could last 3 days without major problems.

The **solution 3** is the easiest IMO, the problem being that the cache HIT will be small, because there are 3m~ records, and each one will have it's own cached lists of related content.

Each solution has it's on ups and downs, and maybe there is something else that you guys can indicate me.

The database in question is MySQL (MariaDB) which - in my opinion - it's a problem by itself.

Comment: You too can upgrade your server's by adding more memory or use ssd.

Comment: How are you fragment caching? Also, are you eager loading? For example, are there n+1 queries happening? You can use the Bullet gem (https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to help find n+1s. With Fastly (fastly.com) which is a really fast Varnish as a service, that can help, however, that's merely masking the underlying issue.